# Bezout's Identity for polynomials

Tags: divisibility, factoring

Im working out a problem where I find out the GCD of two polynomials using Euclid's Algorithm, and then I need to use Bezout's Identity to make

$\gcd(r,s)=ra+sb$

The question gives me 
$x^5+1$ and $x^3+1$ in $F_2[x]$. Using Euclid's Alg. I get

$x^5+1=(x^3+1)x^2+(x^2+1)$

$x^3+1=(x^2+1)x+(x+1)$

$x^2+1=(x+1)(x+1)+0$

So the GCD is $x+1$.

Then, by Bezout's Identity,

(1) $x+1=(x^3+1)+(x^2+1)(x)$

(2) $x+1=(x^3+1)+((x^5+1)+(x^3+1)(x^2))(x)$

This next step is where I am confused. The book gives me

(3) $x+1=(x^5+1)(x)+(x^3+1)(x^3+1)$

However, if I multiply out (2), I get the following:

$x+1=(x^3+1)+(x^5+1)(x)+(x^3+1)(x^2)(x)$

$x+1=(x^3+1)+(x^5+1)(x)+(x^3+1)(x^3)$

So, how does (2) simplify to (3)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arithmetic was explained by John. I explain how to eliminate such  error-prone arithmetic by replacing the painful *back*-substitution with simpler *forward*-computation of the Bezout identity using row-operations. Using the verson of the Extended Euclidean Algorithm [described here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/242) yields

$$\begin{array}{rrr}
(1)\quad x^5+1 &  1 &    0\\
(2)\quad x^3+1  & 0 & 1\\
(1)+x^2(2)\equiv_{2} (3)\quad x^2+1 &  1 &  x^2\\
(2)\ +\ x(3)\equiv_2(4)\quad\ \  x+1 &  \color{#c00}x & \color{#0a0}{x^3+1}\\
(x\!+\!1)(4)+(3)\equiv_2 (5)\qquad\ \  0\quad\! &   \ldots & \ldots
\end{array}\qquad\qquad\qquad\ \ $$

where the above lines $\ a\ \ b\ \ c\ $ denote that  $\ a\, =\, b(x^5+1) + c(x^3+1).\ $ So the Bezout identity is

$$ x+1 \,=\, \color{#c00}{x}(x^5+1)+ (\color{#0a0}{x^3+1})(x^3+1)\quad $$

The linked post describes the algorithm in great detail, in a way that is easy to remember.

---

Here is [another example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/163118/242) computing $\rm\ gcd(141,19),\,$ with the equations written explicitly

$$\rm\begin{eqnarray}(1)\quad \color{#C00}{141}\!\ &=&\,\ \ \ 1&\cdot& 141\, +\ 0&\cdot& 19 \\
(2)\quad\ \color{#C00}{19}\ &=&\,\ \ \ 0&\cdot& 141\, +\ 1&\cdot& 19 \\
\color{#940}{(1)-7\,(2)}\, \rightarrow\, (3)\quad\ \ \ \color{#C00}{ 8}\ &=&\,\ \ \ 1&\cdot& 141\, -\ 7&\cdot& 19 \\
\color{#940}{(2)-2\,(3)}\,\rightarrow\,(4)\quad\ \ \ \color{#C00}{3}\ &=&\, {-}2&\cdot& 141\, + 15&\cdot& 19 \\
\color{#940}{(3)-3\,(4)}\,\rightarrow\,(5)\quad \color{#C00}{{-}1}\ &=&\,\ \ \ 7&\cdot& 141\, -\color{#0A0}{ 52}&\cdot& \color{#0A0}{19} \end{eqnarray}\qquad$$

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{align}
x+1 &= (x^3+1)+(x^5+1)(x)+(x^3+1)(x^3)\\
 &= (x^3+1)(x^3)+(x^3+1)+(x^5+1)(x) \\
 &= (x^3+1)(x^3+1) + (x^5+1)(x)
\end{align}$

The book is grouping terms and pulling out a common factor.