# Finding the Modular Multiplicative Inverse of a large number

Tags: modular-arithmetic, inverse, cryptography, congruences

I am practicing some modular arithmetic and I am trying to find the multiplicative inverse of a large number.
Here is the problem:

345^-1 mod 76408

I'm not sure how to go about solving this problem. I set it up the following way:

x = 345^-1 mod 76408

345x = 1 mod 76408

76408 = 345 * 221 + 163

345 = 163 * 2 + 19

163 = 19 * 8 + 11

19 = 11 * 1 + 8

11 = 8 * 1 + 3

8 = 3 * 2 + 2

3 = 2 * 1 + 1

2 = 1 * 2

I watched a video where i would then use the extended euclidean algorithm, but I'm unsure as to how to do it.

Any help/advice to solve this would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: [This method](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/163118/242) is generally the easiest way to organize the Extended Euclidean Algorithm (to compute modular inverses).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way of writing things: $q_i$ and $r_i$ are the quotient and the remainder of the $i$-th division, $u_i$  and $v_i$ are Bézout's coefficients of $r_i$ relative to $76408$ and $345$ respectively.

The recurrence relations are $$u_{i+1}=u_{i-1}-q_iu_i, \quad v_{i+1}=v_{i-1}-q_iv_i.$$

$$   \begin{array}[t]{r@{\qquad}r@{\qquad}r@{\qquad}r}
  r_i & u_i  & v_i  & q_i\\
   \hline
 76408 & 1 & 0 & \\
  345 & 0 & 1 & 221\\
     \hline
 163 & 1 & -221 & 2\\
 19 & -2 & 443 & 8 \\
11 & 17 & -3765 & 1 \\
 8 & -19 & 4208 & 1\\
 3 & 36 & -7973 & 2\\
 2 & -91 & 20154 & 1\\
 1 & 127 & -28127 \\
     \hline
    \end{array}$$

So $\,1=127\cdot 76408-28127\cdot 345$ from which we conclude $$ 345^{-1}\equiv -28127\equiv  48281\mod 76408. $$

Comment: Remark that this is the same method described in the post linked my above comment.

Comment: Certainly. It's only a systematised version that I didn't discover! You can find it in, say, *Modern Computer Algebra* (by Joachim von zur Gathen and Jürgen Gerhardt.

Comment: In fact it is very old. My remark was merely meant to help guide readers to further examples. Cheers.