# I am stuck on Fermat's Little Theorem. I know how to apply it, but does it apply here $15^{48}$ mod $53$.

Tags: fermat-numbers

I can't seem to figure out this problem. I can factor to reduce the number, but this is too time consuming. Isn't FLT suppose to help here?

Can someone provide clarification please?

[FLT problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pikf.jpg)

Comment: Thank you! This is what I needed. I wasn't sure if I should stop or keep going with the repeated square method.

Comment: I don't see how your hint helps. Can you explicitly state what you are trying to show please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $15^{48}$ is nearly $15^{52}$, we can write

\begin{align}
15^{48} &\equiv 15^{52} \cdot 15^{-4} &\pmod{53}\\
    &= 15^{-4}, &\pmod{53}
\end{align}
using Fermat's little theorem.

With the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm), one can compute $15^{-1} = -7$, and so
\begin{align}
15^{-4} &\equiv (-7)^4 &\pmod{53}\\
        &\equiv 49^2 &\pmod{53}\\
        &\equiv (-4)^2 &\pmod{53}\\
        &\equiv 16. &\pmod{53}
\end{align}

Comment: Alright, I was thinking of this, but are negative exponents allow in modular arithmetic?

Comment: I just tried to solvee the 15^-4 (mod 53) and I get a decimal. I assume that 15^48 is the final answer, right?

Comment: $15^{-1} \bmod{53}$ is well-defined since $\gcd(15, 53) = 1$.

Comment: @J.DoeHue, yes, they are, provided the number being negatively exponentiated is relatively prime to the modulus (which is the certainly the case here, in part since $53$ is a prime number).

Comment: @J.DoeHue I've expanded my answer.

Comment: Alright, I think I understand now. Thanks. I'll try it out to see how it works. So 15-1 = -7 is like saying 15 inverse = -7 in modulo 53? Is this correct?

Comment: @J.DoeHue Yes, it means that $15 \cdot (-7) \equiv 1 \pmod{53}$; i.e., they are multiplicative inverses.

Comment: OMG! Thanks a ton. This is what I need to find, but couldn't else where.

Comment: @J.DoeHue Besides the [extended Euclidean algorithm,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/163118/242) below are a couple other ways to invert $15$, the first being [Gauss's algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/174687/242)

$$\bmod 53\!:\,\ \dfrac{1}{15}\equiv \dfrac{3}{45}\equiv \dfrac{56}{-8}\equiv  -7$$

$$\bmod 53\!:\,\ \dfrac{1}{15}\equiv \dfrac{54}{3\cdot 5}\equiv \dfrac{18}5\equiv \dfrac{-35}5\equiv -7$$

Answer (score 0):

$15^{48}*15^{4} = 15^{52}\equiv 1\pmod {53}$ by FLT.

As $53$ is prime all terms have a multiplicative inverses and $\mathbb Z/53\mathbb Z$ is a field.  So if we can know what $15^{-1}\pmod {53}$ is (i.e. then $x$ so that $15\equiv 1 \pmod{53}$) is then $15^{48} \equiv (15^{-1})^4=(15^4)^{-1} \pmod {53}$.

$15^4 \equiv 225^2 \equiv 13^2 \equiv 169\equiv 10\pmod {53}$.

So what is $10^{-1}\pmod{53}$ so that $10^{-1}*10\equiv 1 \pmod{53}$?

Well. $53*3= 159$ so $10*16 = 159 + 1\equiv 1\pmod{53}$.

So $10^{-1}\equiv 16\pmod {53}$ and $15^{48} \equiv 16\pmod {53}$.

And we can verify this as $16*15^4 \equiv 30^4 =810000\equiv 1 \equiv 15^{52}$ and as $\gcd(15, 53)=1$ then means $16\equiv 15^{48}\pmod {53}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is the solution that I was searching for, I just didn't understand how to put together the concepts.

Comment: @J.DoeHue This is the same as Zach's prior answer except for order, i.e. here $(15^4)^{-1}$ vs. $(15^{-1})^4$ there.

Comment: Same answer.  Different explanation how to come by it.